# Stopping jQuery onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am totally newbie in jquery and I need to change jquery slideshow function to work only onmouseout. Simple - If somebody will hover #slideshow div than slideshow will stop switching images.
here is my slideshow script:

```
   $("#slideshow").mouseout() {

        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  2000);

    });
```

and here is my $slideshow div

```
<div class="ss">
                        <div id="slideshow">
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/ss.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/ss2.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/ss3.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>text</p>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var initList=setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  2000); 
$('#slideshow').mouseover(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
 }).mouseout(function(){
    initList = setInterval(function(){ $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');}, 2000) ;
 });
```

I think it will work. 
So, when mouseover occurs the interval cleared from the initList. Again when mouseout the same can be applied to the initList

Comment: Can you tell the OP what you did? Explain that you named the setInterval so that you could clear it and restart it? That way,the OP and future generations of SO'er's will learn not only how, but why you did what you did.

Comment: thank you sir. I will keep this in my mind @JayBlanchard